# Are Pearson test and Chi-square test the same?

Tags: chi-squared-test, terminology

I'm a bit confused with Chi-square and Pearson. I know Chi-square is:

`Chi-square = E (sum of) (Oi - Ei)-square / Ei`

What would the Pearson formula be if it is different?

Comment: The chi-square statistic (in your notation $\sum (O_i - E_i)^2/E_i$ for observed frequencies $O_i$ and expected frequencies $E_i$) is often called the Pearson chi-square statistic, because Karl Pearson used it. If this doesn't answer your question, you need to rewrite it because it is not very clear.

Comment: It does thank you Nick! So it's the same thing. Is there a non-Pearson Chi-square?

Comment: No. @Nick didn't say they are not the same.

Comment: Karl Pearson and Egon Pearson between them are associated with quite a few tests, so you're going to have to help us disambiguate a little -- in what context did you see the term "Pearson test"? Was it in a book, perhaps, or a paper, for example?

Comment: im also confuse please simply differentiate both ... pearson chi square can be used as an inferential test of the independence of two nominal variables . and chi-squared test can be used to attempt rejection of the null hypothesis that the data are independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chi-square test is a family of statistical tests that uses the chi-square distribution for statistical testing. That includes Pearson's chi-square testing.

In Pearson's chi-square testing, the test statistic

[image]

can be shown follow a chi-square distribution asymptotically.

Therefore, they are not the same. Pearson's test is simply the most common chi-square test.

Comment: Erm..... I'm confused. Is that the same Nick wrote above? I kind of understood it is the same

Comment: @Bolton No. Nick didn't say they are the same thing. He was just telling you your formula is called Pearson's because it was used by Pearson.

Comment: OK thanks, I did kudos but it didn't take it for some reason

Comment: Other flavours of chi-square include likelihood ratio chi-square. (You can't upvote until you have reputation 15 if that's what you mean by your reference to kudos. You did accept the answer.)

Comment: 1. The test statistic on count data actually *doesn't* follow a chi-square distribution for any finite sample size; there's an asymptotic result (that is, in the limit as $n\to\infty$ it goes to the chi-square; in finite samples it's discrete (and in many cases, the approximation by the asymptotic distribution is quite reasonable). $\,$ 2. If possible, can you give an reference (a book or paper, say) where Pearson's chi-square test is just called "Pearson's test"?

Answer (score 1):

Glen_b. This is a good reference to read about Pearson's chi-square test: http://www.jstor.org/stable/1402731?seq=1#fndtn-page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: This is okay.  I think people know that the chi square test for contingency tables and for goodness of fit are referred to as Karl Pearson's.  But testing the significance of bivariate correlation is also referred to as Pearson's.